# Linq Expression Builder datetime.year compare

Tags: linq, entity-framework, expression-trees, dynamic-linq

Currently I am using expression builder for dynamic query generation.

I have created dynamic expressions for int, date time, and string operators. Now I am stuck at one point .

I want to compare month part of datetime through expression.

We are passing property of datetime and want to create expression for month of that property.

Code:

```
public static Expression GetDynamicquery<TSource>(
        string property, object value, ParameterExpression p)
    {

        var propertyReference = Expression.Property(p, property);


        var constantReference = Expression.Constant(value);
        var expression = Expression.Equal(propertyReference, constantReference);
        MethodInfo method = null;



                return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(propertyReference, constantReference);



    }
```

Here property is name of property which I am passing into Tsource.

`p` is parameter expression of type Tsource.

I want result like all birthdate of this month.

Comment: What does your code do now?

Comment: @user1522548 
It's partial code but the idea was creating dynamic linq queries using opertaors enum and for all dayatype.
and I want to access the year property of datetime datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer of my question. What I did is like....

Code:

```
public static Expression GetDynamicquery<TSource>(
    string property, object value, ParameterExpression p)
{

    var propertyReference = Expression.Property(p, property);

    propertyReference = Expression.Property(propertyReference, "Year");

    var constantReference = Expression.Constant(value);
    return Expression.Equal(propertyReference, constantReference);
}
```

Here first property reference will give datetime expression.

And again using that expression we can go one step inside and can access year property.
Same thing we can do for month.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
Expression.PropertyOrField method for that.
Not sure it would work with entity framework query though.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.propertyorfield(v=vs.110).aspx

Update

For entity framework you can use SqlFunctions.DatePart method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx

You would need an Expression.Call to represent that as an expression.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb349020(v=vs.110).aspx